# What is the difference between the yellow and brown exploding barrels?

Tags: a-wizards-lizard

There are two kinds of exploding barrels in A Wizard's Lizard, the normal brown ones and the jittery yellow/golden ones, as depicted in this screenshot:

[image: Different kinds of barrels]

I always thought the yellow ones would have a larger blast radius, but a recent test proved me wrong: The blast radius of both kinds of barrels is one space.

What's the difference, then?